# Unable to find correct strings.xml for a given locale

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-resources

I'm supporting Hindi Locale in my android application. For this I've added strings.xml in a new values-hi folder.

After this I set my resource.configuration.locale to "hi" from a separate activity in my app.

When I debug where any string is been set to a view, I found that the locale was already set to "hi" , but on evaluating

`getString(R.string.title)` it returned the default value from default strings.xml file located in values folder.

Please help me out on how to solve this.

I'm adding my Locale manager used to set the Locale,

```
public class LocaleManager {

public static final  String LANGUAGE_ENGLISH   = "en";
private static final String LANGUAGE_KEY       = "language_key";

private final SharedPreferences prefs;

public LocaleManager(Context context) {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}

public Context setLocale(Context c) {
    return updateResources(c, getLanguage());
}

public Context setNewLocale(Context c, String language) {
    persistLanguage(language);
    return updateResources(c, language);
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return prefs.getString(LANGUAGE_KEY, LANGUAGE_ENGLISH);
}

@SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
private void persistLanguage(String language) {
    // use commit() instead of apply(), because sometimes we kill the application process immediately
    // which will prevent apply() to finish
    prefs.edit().putString(LANGUAGE_KEY, language).commit();
}

private Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    if (Utility.isAtLeastVersion(JELLY_BEAN_MR1)) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}

public static Locale getLocale(Resources res) {
    Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
    return Utility.isAtLeastVersion(N) ? config.getLocales().get(0) : config.locale;
}
```

}`

Also I've added following lines in my Application.java and BaseActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {

super.attachBaseContext(TBApplication.localeManager.setLocale(base));
    Log.d(TAG, "attachBaseContext");
}
```

Comment: You may have to set your phone language Hindi.

Comment: show how you set the locale

Comment: I've updated the question with code